# How to make a clickable link in pdf footer using wkhtmltopdf?

Tags: html, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

We want to use links in the pdf footer. We utilize `wkhtmltopdf` tool to generate our pdfs.

`wkhtmltopdf` wrongly places the clickable area few millimeters above the link itself
[image: bug screenshot]

When we use absolute links in the footer like `https://google.com` pdf viewers recognize the links and allow to click on it
[image]

But we would like to show custom text for our links like `Terms and conditions` and so on. As a possible workaround, we were trying to overlay our link text over a transparent link using absolute positioning ([codepen](https://codepen.io/glebbb/pen/NWzdBKV)). It works well for html but doesn't work for pdfs.

Do we have some other possible options to get around the issue?

Comment: We'd like to use something like this in the footer [Terms and conditions](https://example.com/TermsNconditions.html)

Comment: Yes, it's a known issue with `wkhtmltopdf` [link](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/5026#issuecomment-867989808) but we can't painlessly switch to another one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We implemented a JS workaround where we duplicate footer content and move it down by 135px. So the footer replica is invisible to the end users but it provides clickable areas for the original footer. We could do it because we have constant top and bottom margins.
[image]